# How can I download images from OpenImages

Tags: python

I am trying to donwload a subset of images from Google OpenImages. When I run this sentences in a Jupyter notebook:

```
from openimages.download import download_images
oi_download_images --csv_dir /openimages --base_dir /openimages --labels Scissors --limit 100
```

I get this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-4-b3df9acf4e8e>", line 2
    oi_download_images --csv_dir /openimages --base_dir /openimages --labels Scissors --limit 100
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Where did you find this openimages library? That looks like a shell script, not a python script

Comment: @C_Z_ Specifically, the line starting with `oi_download_images` looks like a shell command. The `from` line looks like Python, but it doesn't seem directly related to the other line.

Comment: Yes: you are right. Indeed the example that I reviewed has the symbol $ before the line starting with oi_download_images, hence this line is a shell script

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown for `oi_download_images` is a shell command tool, not a Python script. You can't input that command directly into IPython, it must be executed on a shell itself (like `cmd.exe`, `bash`, `zsh` and so on).

After installing it with `pip install openimages` the shell command tool `oi_download_images` is going to be available to execute. Execute it like the following [(adapted from the docs)](https://github.com/monocongo/openimages#usage-examples):

```bash
oi_download_images --base_dir ./openimages --labels Scissors --limit 4
```

And you get 4 images like:

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The other way around, if you'd like to run it in Python (IPython / Jupyter) as a script or a command. To do the same as above do the following:

1. Create an empty file `exclusions.txt`
2. ```py
   from openimages.download import download_images
   download_images("./openimages", ["Scissors"], '/path/to/exclusions.txt', limit=4)
   ```

Or like this with `!` in front of the shell command, [the IPython System Shell Access](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#system-shell-access) in IPython/Jupyter itself:

```py
!oi_download_images --base_dir ./openimages --labels Scissors --limit 4
```

Comment: You can input shell scripts into **iPython** using `!oi_download_images`, for example.

Comment: Oh yeah. IPython supports running it with `!` operator. Thanks for pointing that out @OneCricketeer

Comment: Many thanks. I have run the line !oi_download_images --base_dir ./openimages --labels Scissors --limit 100 in a Jupyter notebook and I have gotten 100 scissor's images (every imagen into a jpg file). That is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/monocongo/openimages#download-images-and-annotations)?

You've imported a module function. Then you need to call that function, not skip down and copy the *other example* that is a CLI action.

```
from openimages.download import download_images
download_images("/openimages", ["Scissors"], limit=100)
```

Comment: When I run this option in a Jupyter notebook I get this error: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-77616dbde4ef> in <module>
----> 1 download_images("/openimages", ["Scissors"], limit=100)

TypeError: download_images() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exclusions_path' Nevertheless I can get the images with the option pointed in the first answer, many thanks!

Comment: If that's a required parameter, you should open a github issue saying the documentation is incorrect